# How can I Change RibbonApplicationMenu to flat

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am developing a paint wpf application. In my application, i use a Ribbon. How can I make the RibbonApplicationMenu is flat like window 10 Paint RibbonApplicationMenu.
Thank you.

Comment: What kind of Ribbon Framework do you use?

Comment: i am using visual studio 2012 .net 4.5

Comment: I didn't ask for your IDE :) . What kind of DLL are you using for Ribbon? The Microsoft Ribbon Framework? Or any other 3rd party Framework like Telerik or Fluent?

Comment: I use The Microsoft Ribbon Framework :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try the Microsoft Component yet but I doubt they have a Windows 10 Theme for its Ribbon Framework. You can take a look at this free 3rd party Component. They don't have a Windows 10 Look but a Windows 8 as well as Office 2013 Theme. Maybe this is useful.

It's also available via NuGet

https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon

[image: Fluent Ribbon Preview]

Comment: I got it. Thanks for answering.